# How do I assign app priority for gesture controls?

Tags: windows, firefox, spotify, gesture, touchpad

I am using Windows 11 and I have my three-finger tap gesture set to "play/pause". It works for spotify as long as I don't have a video on youtube open at the same time. It assigns priority to the youtube video and no longer works for pausing music in Spotify, even when I minimize my browser (Firefox) and maximize Spotify.

I want to assign priority for the play/pause to spotify. How can I do that?

I would prefer a way that does not require any third-party software, maybe there is a setting in Firefox that makes it ignore the gesture?

Thank you!

Comment: This is not a [suitable topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for StackOverflow!